# Inversion of Control < Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, terminology

I'm getting the feeling that there's is not such thing as inversion of control or rather the correct term is dependency injection. Am I wrong to assume this?

I've been trying to define IoC for my own sake. In doing so I've learned a great deal about IoC containers and dependency injection.

Just now, I read this from [Martin Fowler's website](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl):

> As a result I think we need a more
>   specific name for this pattern.
>   Inversion of Control is too generic a
>   term, and thus people find it
>   confusing. As a result with a lot of
>   discussion with various IoC advocates
>   we settled on the name Dependency
>   Injection.

In the world of modern IoC isn't dependency injection just one way to achieve IoC?

Comment: For understanding the concept and importance of Dependency Injection refer to http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/05/understanding-dependency-injection-and.html And for a complete example of bean wiring with Spring Framework http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/05/dependency-injection-with-java-spring.html It is described in simple way...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you accept [Fowler's definition](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html), Inversion of Control is a much **broader** term than DI that covers all **framework** usage where you plug into a framework, but the framework is still in control.

For example, in .NET, frameworks such as ASP.NET or Windows Presentation Foundation are ultimately in control, but provide various **events** and **Seams** you can use to build an application. The same is true on other platforms.

**Dependency Injection** is a **specialization** of IoC that applies IoC specifically to manage dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify things. Do you know of a place where I might find more examples of IoC?

Comment: In reality, IoC (as opposed to DI) is everywhere in OO. It's harder to find examples of the opposite. I'm only really knowledgeable of the .NET platform, but almost any type of sub-framework you use there (ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WCF etc.) are IoC frameworks. Only console apps really fall outside of this category.

Comment: That's an assurance given Fowler's statement: "Inversion of Control is too generic a term". To be more specific, I'd love to see DP and IoC examples. I'm really hung up on learning more about how to achive good IoC through DP.

Comment: @Mark - Yes, silly typo. I'm learning about how to leverage IoC and DI and code examples would definitely go along way there.

Comment: Well, I *am* working on a book on the subject if you can read C# examples... http://www.manning.com/seemann/

Answer (score 6):

That's one of the few points me and Mark disagree on. By my book, Inversion of Control  **principle** is [same as here](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inversion-of-Control.ashx) so I won't rehash it.

Dependency injection is merely an act of externalizing **creation** of dependencies to the outside world by components.

Managing these dependencies (and lots of other stuff) is what **Inversion of Control Containers** do, and using DI as part of it, is merely an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, IoC means the class itself does not control things, but is called from outside. Dependency injection is the way to do this.

Dependency injection is indeed a much more concrete term, more well-defined than inversion of control.