# Inversion Of Control vs Dependency Injection with selected quotes – is my understanding correct?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've read a number of threads explaining the difference between **IoC** and **DI** and while many of explanations contradicted each other, I think they still  helped me understand the difference.

So here I'd like to ask whether my understanding is correct and also post excerpts that helped me ( though some of them contradict each other ).

I know there have been lots of threads done on the subject, but I'm hoping this thread won't get closed since I don't think any of OPs in mentioned threads also showed all the relevant posts ( from various threads ) that helped them finally understand it.

Anyways, here is how I understand it (if possible,please address/answer each question individually ):

a) When we apply **DIP** principle at the *framework level*, then we use the term **IoC**? And one of the mechanisms to implement **DIP** at *framework level* is **DI**?

b) The term **IoC** does not apply when we implement **DIP** ( using **DI** ) at a *lower level/non-framework level*, in which case we simply call it **DI**?

c) **DI** helps us to achive **DIP** by passing the control of the actual creation of and selection of dependencies to a 3rd party which is neutral to either of the other 2 involved?

d) When **DIP** is applied ( using **DI** ) at *framework level* (IoC), then three types of control get inverted:

1. **The control of the interface.** Now high level module is controlling the interface that the lower level modules need to adhere to instead of the other way around
2. **The control of the flow.** --> Now *framework code* ( instead of *user/business code* ) controls the flow of the program ( in other words - *they ( ie framework ) call you ( ie business code )*  )
3. **The control of dependency creation**. This inversion is passing the control of the actual creation and selection of dependencies to a 3rd party which is neutral to either of the other 2 involved.

e) When **DIP** is applied (using **DI**) at *non-framework level*, then two types of control get inverted:

1. **The control of the interface.** Now high level module is controlling the interface that the lower level modules need to adhere to instead of the other way around
2. **The control of dependency creation**. This inversion is passing the control of the actual creation and selection of dependencies to a 3rd party which is neutral to either of the other 2 involved.

?

Here are excerpts that helped:

[Why so many terms to say the same thing? IoC and DIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327822/why-so-many-terms-to-say-the-same-thing-ioc-and-dip)

> Inversion of Control is the generic term. Dependency Injection is a
> specific type of IoC
>
> ...
>
> Inversion of Control is when the framework/infrastructure invokes
> application code, rather than the other way around
>
> ...
>
> can do DI without doing IoC. If you inject aConsoleStringWriter into a
> HelloWorld I don't really think of this as IoC because there is no
> "framework" or "infrastructure".

[Inversion of Control < Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226605/inversion-of-control-dependency-injection)

> If you accept Fowler's definition, Inversion of Control is a much
> broader term than DI that covers allframework usage where you plug
> into a framework, but the framework is still in control. Dependency
> Injection is a specialization of IoC that applies IoC specifically to
> manage dependencies.

[Where exactly is the difference between IoC and DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596300/where-exactly-is-the-difference-between-ioc-and-di)

> IoC is the ability to vary the implementation of a contract. DI is the
> ability to supply the implementation.
>
> ...
>
> In traditional applications, developers would write business code and
> framework code. The business code would then call the framework code
> to accomplish tasks. Under an IoC model, you "invert" that model and
> create a framework that accepts business modules and calls them to
> accomplish tasks
>
> Dependency Injection is a technique (hard to call it a pattern,
> really) of removing internal dependencies from implementations by
> allowing dependent objects to be injected into the class/method by an
> external caller. IoC frameworks use dependency injection to supply
> user modules and other dependent code to framework routines that "glue
> it all together." Dependency injection is used heavily by IoC
> frameworks because that is the mechanism that allows them to "Call
> You."

[DIP vs. DI vs. IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766056/dip-vs-di-vs-ioc)

> DIP is the principle that guides us towards DI. Basically, loose
> coupling is the goal, and there are at least two ways to achieve it.
> • Dependency Injection •  Service Locator

[Does anyone have a good analogy for dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424457/does-anyone-have-a-good-analogy-for-dependency-injection)

> The essence of Inversion of Control (of which Dependency Injection is
> an implementation) is the separation of the use of an object from the
> management thereof.

[Difference between ioc and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402720/difference-between-ioc-and-dependency-injection)

> The terms Dependency Injection (DI) & Inversion of Control (IoC) are
> generally used interchangeably to describe the same design pattern
> (although not everyone agrees on that point, and some people tend to
> apply them in slightly different ways). The pattern was originally
> called IoC, but Martin Fowler proposed the shift to DI because all
> frameworks invert control in some way and he wanted to be more
> specific about which aspect of control was being inverted.

[Inversion of Control vs Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550700/inversion-of-control-vs-dependency-injection)

> Inversion of Control (IoC) means that objects do not create other
> objects on which they rely to do their work. Instead, they get the
> objects that they need from an outside source (for example, an xml
> configuration file). Dependency Injection (DI) means that this is done
> without the object intervention, usually by a framework component that
> passes constructor parameters and set properties.

thank you

Comment: Note that SO isn't a forum, so it doesn't have "threads". It's a Q&A site, so it has questions and answers. This isn't a minor distinction, as the difference in formats have a number of consequences. Also, [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for conceptual & design questions. SO is for implementation issues.

Comment: [This book](http://manning.com/seemann/) will give you all the answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well this is my point of view:

[image: DI Overview]

**DIP** means that you program against an abstraction. You invert the kind of a dependency from an implementation to an abstraction.

**IOC** means that somebody else is responsible for getting the implementation for the given abstraction. Normally the consumer would use the **new** keyword to get a dependency. With IoC you invert the control, so that the consumer is not responsible for creating the instance anymore.

**Dependency Injection** and **Service Location** are a part of **Inversion of Control**.
[image: DIvsSL]

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053413/175399

Comment: 1 - According to one of the quotes, we're also able to do DI without IoC ( when we implement DIP via DI at non-framework level ). Would you agree? 2 - Anyways, I assume a,b,c and d are all correct?

Comment: 1 When using IoC the consumer of a dependency is not responsible for creating an instance. If you create the instance with a framework or not does not matter. You should seperate the principles/methologies from the frameworks.

Comment: This is an awesome illustration - possibly the most obvious explanation I've seen, written or drawn :-)