# Does the Facade Pattern violates the SOLID principles?

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles, facade

I ask my self if the Facade Pattern violates the SOLID principles and if the pattern itself is an Anti Pattern.

**UPDATED**

My Opinions:

- **SRP** is violated, when you don't just call methods directly, but do 
  things like Transactions, Logging, Error Handling (What I have seen a lot of times). Even with just calling other methods I am in doubt.
- **OCP** is violated, because you will add more methods to the facade
- **LSP**/**ISP** is violated, because the consumer/client has dependency that will have too much methods, which the client does not need.
- **DIP**, is in my opinion not violated as long as the interface itself only exposes abstraction or DTOs.

**SOLID** in general is in my opinion about **small**, **stable** and thereby **composable** interfaces.

A *facade* tends to be the opposite **big** and **not stable**.

Comment: You mean all SOLID principles?? or some specific one?

Comment: I would say SRP, Liskovk and Interface Segregation.

Comment: In general I can myself see violation of OCP. And you might refer the Facade class, as violating SRP. Rest of your question might be pretty much implementation specific. Could you please elaborate with an example, giving where it violates those principles? or a link of a specific implementation you found??

Comment: only correct answer is "it depends", oh and `subjective`

Comment: @Rookian just saw your edit. In your opinions, I think for SRP and OCP, I have put same thought in my answer. :) One addition is you have to violate OCP whenever you have a new requirement to add inside an existing file, which is not only 'Facade' specific. But for LSP/ISP, I don't understand your point. It's true that the client is dependent with Facade. Does it mean it's violating LSP/ISP ??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne If you only need one method of the facade but the facade offers i.e. 12 methods it violates the ISP imo. Imagine you need to implement that interface and you only care about 2 methods, because you only need two methods, then it would be strange to throw NotSupportExceptions for the rest of the not used methods (violation of LSP).

Comment: @Rookian I think your opinion is wrong about ISP and LSP. ISP just states program to interface rather implementation. LSP states that any interface 'implementing' should not have excess options which are not fits  for the classes that are going to implement it. ex: Circle-elipse problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem . In this case the client is not implementing(inheriting) the facade. right? Any way I definitely agree with your last idea 'A facade tends to be the opposite big and not stable'. It's all about what the priority is. :)

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Sry, but you mix up some of the principles. "The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use." What you mean is the dependency inversion principle. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11319026/175399.

Comment: @Rookian in simple direct English meaning, Interface Segregation -> Segregate(separate) the interface -> i.e. Abstract out any interface you find before doing any specific implementation.

Answer (score 8):

In general idea without considering any implementation specifics, we can consider **Facade** as a way of hiding a set of sub-systems with a higher level wrapper class using **Composition and Encapsulation**. The higher level **Wrapper** class is the one that always talks with any client and the **Sub-systems** consisted inside the wrapper are the ones that are really doing the jobs.

Example:

```
public class Bulb{

    public void on(){
        //logic to turn on the bulb.
    }

}

public class Room{

   private Bulb bulb;

   public void lightUp(){
        this.bulb.on();
   }
}
```

In above Bulb is a sub-system and Room is the wrapper (Facade). So a client would like to see as it is directly lighting up the room and not interested in knowing what it has to be done with the bulb.

So back into your question, If we take SOLID principles one by one.

1. SRP: You should be thinking that, the wrapper class violates this principle, because it is doing more than a single duty. But on the other hand, it is just calling some others to do them, and not holding the implementation with the wrapper. Anyway that thought can be much personal one.
2. OCP: Definitely yes, if you are adding some more subsystems/functionalities. Meantime you can use some modern implementation binding framework to avoid violating OCP in this situation.
3. LSP: In general I don't find any. But there can be situations which are implementation specific, not with the pattern.
4. ISP: Same as LSP.
5. DIP: Same as LSP, ISP.

And about considering Facade as an anti-pattern (Cons of Facade),

1. One can see, It is increasing the maintenance effort. For some changes you have to change the sub-system(s) implementation + respective wrapper calls.
2. Sub-systems are tightly coupled with the Wrapper.
3. It is some what procedural and a bit away from object orientation.

Still the choice of using Facade(Many patterns) would be by personal flavor.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it out in [this](https://medium.com/@dizaji.akbar/anti-patterns-that-assumed-as-pattern-part2-facade-2452ae6166b3) post.

Comment: this can be a comment to question rather than an answer