# Why Dependency Injection is also called Inverstion of control (IOC)

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inversion of Control < Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226605/inversion-of-control-dependency-injection)

I know what dependency injection is but trying to understand why its also know as Inversion of Control.

Answer (score 3):

Inversion of control is a *principle* and dependency injection is a *technique*. The distinction is subtle and most people refer to them interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means that not the components itself are in control for looking up and instantiating their dependencies anymore.

The term Dependency Injection came up in Martin Fowlers great [article on Inversion Of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html):

> As a result I think we need a more specific name for this pattern.
>   Inversion of Control is too generic a term, and thus people find it
>   confusing. As a result with a lot of discussion with various IoC
>   advocates we settled on the name Dependency Injection.